# How can a user get the Custodian badge with a reputation lower than 500?

Tags: support, badges

If I understand correctly, Custodian badge will be awarded to users who completed at least one review task. To complete a [review](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review) task user should have at least a reputation of 500. (As of my understand from this [page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review)). If this is correct, how could this [user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/26119/anees) get that badge?

Comment: Ok I think I got the answer.
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/28680
I just went this user activity, and got clear Idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, access to the review queues requires 500 rep (see [Privileges](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)).  However, users can also review suggested edits to their own posts.  I suspect the user got the badge from [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/106822/revisions).

Comment: Yes I got it now.